# React Testing Library - Get by text when some of the text is inside an anchor tag

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I wish to find some text by a full string of text which contains an anchor.

```html
<div>
  <div>
    Hey im some text <a>with a link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I attempt to retrieve this with

```
screen.getByText(/hey im some text with a link/i)
```

However, react testing library does not find it. How can I get react testing library to pick up text inside children?

Answer (score 0):

Please check point 4 in this post [Queries accept functions too](https://polvara.me/posts/five-things-you-didnt-know-about-testing-library).

```js
screen.getByText((content, node) => {
    const hasText = (node) => node.textContent === "Hey im some text with a link";
    const nodeHasText = hasText(node);
    const childrenDontHaveText = Array.from(node.children).every(
      (child) => !hasText(child)
    );

    return nodeHasText && childrenDontHaveText;
});
```